MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed
In my web application, it works most of the time, but occasionally I get a 500 error, and sometimes I don’t.
It works completle in local server, but the preblem is in the website that use MongoDB atlas.
My app is in svelte/sveltikit and typescript.
Example: I am logged into the app and can log out and register a new user; it works 90% of the time. However, sometimes, when I logged out and want register a new user’s, ican can navigare to the register-page, enter the information and whene i click register I get an error 500.
I'm not sure why this error occurs, but the message is coming from the server:
MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed
    at processWaitQueue (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.3.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:509:46)
    at Topology.selectServer (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.3.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:280:9)
    at Topology.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.3.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:41:94)
    at node:internal/util:432:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Topology.selectServerAsync (node:internal/util:418:12)
    at executeOperationAsync (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.3.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:77:35)
    at /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.3.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:12:45
    at maybeCallback (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.3.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:270:21)
    at executeOperation (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.3.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:12:38) {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

My MongoDB file:
const client = new MongoClient(URI);

export async function connect() {
await client.connect();
}

export async function disconnect() {
await client.close();
}

export function getDB() {
return client.db();
}

I am new with MongoDB and web application.
I’ve tried numerous solutions without success, Like:
Add &connectTimeoutMS=50000&socketTimeoutMS=50000 to the URI link to Mongo Atlas
I have read about changeing MongoClient:
const client = MongoClient(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

But i get an error in VSCode under useNewUrlParser:

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useNewUrlParser' does not exist in type 'MongoClientOptions'.ts(2353)

Any ideas on how to fix it?
